# Issue in Building application in xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an issue when running the application.
I got error Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 Error

```
Command /Applications/Xcode46-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I quit and reopen the project and click clean

Also i have same issue.  Can any one advice me how to fix the issue

Thanks in advance.

I am using Xcode 4.6 IOS 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deactivating the use of precompiled headers in Xcode's build-settings. That may fix the issue.

Comment: glad to hear that it has been fixed

Comment: Same error here, but deactivating the use of precompiled headers has no effect (even after a clean an run) : clang: error: unknown warning option '-Wno-pragmas'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1